# box shadow in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, css

I've been working on some buttons using css3 effects such as border-radius, box-shadow, and linear-gradient. For IE8 and lower, I'm using PIE to create the desired effect but it seems box-shadow works on IE8 without using PIE. Does IE8 actually support the box-shadow property?

Answer (score 0):

According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow) box-shadow is not supported but it "can be partially emulated in older IE versions using the non-standard "shadow" filter." So, if you're using -ms-filter or filter as a fallback it will render in a visually similar manner to the CSS3 box-shadow declaration. If that is not the case then you should check to see if you are using another polyfill to generate box-shadow support.

You can use [IE8's developer tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to see exactly what styles are being recognized and rendered.

Comment: I found '<outset-box-shadow style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;" checkedByCssHelper="true">' inside a css3 container so PIE must be rendering the box-shadow. I'm already using it for border-radius so it's using the same behaviour:url(PIE.htc) reference for the box-shadow. I thought I had to make a separate reference if I wanted a box-shadow.

Comment: Depending on the use situation it might not even be worth using PIE to emulate all the CSS3 features. It may slow down the old browsers to a point that detracts from the usability you're trying to add. Often, a graceful fallback approach is preferred (e.g. don't even render box-shadows in old browsers unless the shadow is really, really important to the design).

Comment: Yeah, good point. Sometimes it's just not worth the time and effort.